# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code:

```
string idString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; 
int customerID = int.Parse(idString);

Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == customerID);
customer.FirstName = cart.BillingInfo.FirstName;
customer.LastName = cart.BillingInfo.LastName;
customer.BillingAddress = cart.BillingInfo.Address;
customer.BillingCity = cart.BillingInfo.City;
customer.BillingState = cart.BillingInfo.State;
customer.BillingPostalCode = cart.BillingInfo.Zip;
customer.CardNumber = cart.BillingInfo.CreditCardNumber;
customer.ExpirationMonth = cart.BillingInfo.ExpirationMonth;
customer.ExpirationYear = cart.BillingInfo.ExpirationYear;

db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>    System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +11174263
>    System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145
>    System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
>    DJMaxStore.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.ProcessOrder(ShoppingCartModel cart) in c:\Users\irosario\Desktop\DJMaxStore\DJMaxStore\Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs:109
>    DJMaxStore.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.BillingInfo(BillingInfo billingInfo) in c:\Users\irosario\Desktop\DJMaxStore\DJMaxStore\Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs:96
>    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
>    System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
>    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9650772
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
> ```
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36283

Comment: Could you please a) edit your question to format your code snippets as code (this makes them easier to read) and b) clarify what specific question you're asking? You've described an error but it's not entirely clear what you'd like StackOverflow to do with it. Thanks!

Comment: I've corrected my answer. You are getting a string from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` which is unconvertible to integer, hence the exception occures.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 
`System.Int32.Parse(String s)` (inside the `ShoppingCartController.ProcessOrder` method)
takes the invalid argument. Check what is passed to that method. Is that an int number?

EDIT:

You are trying to convert string to integer. If `idString` is not in the correct format (not a number), then you will get `System.FormatException`. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: It's an input string error, a system.exception, I write string data through fields in the web app and is passed along as httpcontext, for some reason the conversion is not working here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to parse a string that cannot be converted to an integer. Use `int.TryParse()` method

```
 int myInt;
 var result = int.TryParse("23", out myInt);

 if (result == true)
 {
    // do something...
 }
```